# How to Upgrade Laravel 5.4 to Laravel 7.12

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-permission, entrust

In my old project laravel 5.4, use zizaco/entrust and it's doesn't support laravel 7. So I would like to use spatie/laravel-permission.

Could you please guide me how to do it.

Comment: With that kind of question, you won't have a precise answer as there are many ways to proceed. I recommend installing a fresh Laravel 7 version. Migrate routes, models, migrations, views and controllers after.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got the solution to this issue. Please go through the steps I have used.

-Run command php artisan make:provider EntrustCustomServiceProvider -go to app/Providers/EntrustCustomServiceProvider.php Use Auth; and Write in the boot function

[Link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/entrust-at-role-and-at-permission-directives-not-rendering-in-blade-laravel-56)

Check this method:
Now I found other github name greatsami-master support for laravel 7 (it's forked from zizaco entrust too).https://github.com/greatsami/entrust